# About multiple lambdas from one sqs queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Just a question about AWS Lambda and SQS:

Can we set up multiple lambdas to consume different events from one SQS queue based on event type. For example: reporting events to be consumed by reporting lambda and registration events to be consumed by registration lambda.

Or should set up different queues for different events which will be hard to maintain as there can be multiple events.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you **can't choose** which messages you are going to get in your lambda function. You can only ignore "wrong messages" in your function, or write `if-else` type logic to process different messages in a different way.

The better technique is to have **different queues** for different message types along with the **corresponding functions**.

Comment: one way (not the good one) is to have a single consumer lambda + sub lambdas (report, registration) . Consumer lambda decides which lambda to be invoked depending on the input inside the message.

Comment: Yes, which is basically `if-else` type logic in the consumer lambda. Except that now you have 3 lambdas to maintain, instead of 2.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the insightful reply guys.